# @cachable issue - method not caching

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ehcache

I have a method that uses the @Cachable

```
@Cacheable(value="airport", key="#filter")
public static String getAirport(String filter, SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    String airportsDisplay = "";
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    airportsDisplay = (String) session.createQuery("select iata from Airports a where a.displaystr = :accfilter").setString("accfilter", filter.toUpperCase()).uniqueResult();
    session.close();
    return airportsDisplay;
}
```

All it does is a database query with the given filter and returns an airport name.

the xml configuratin is

```
<cache name="airport"
   maxElementsInMemory="100"
   eternal="false"
   timeToIdleSeconds="1200"
   timeToLiveSeconds="1200"
   overflowToDisk="true"
   maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
   diskPersistent="true"
   diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="1200"
   memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
```

The problem is that it does not cache the results!

on deployment the airport.data gets created normally BUT it is always empty no matter how many times I call the method from my web app.

Anny suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method is static, so it's not part of a Spring bean and Spring can't intercept the call to the method and return a cached result instead of invoking it. Only Spring bean methods can be made cacheable.

Comment: So if i remove the static keyword and annotate the class @Service it will work?

Comment: Yes, it will work if you inject an instance of this service into the calling Spring bean (or get a reference to the service using the bean factory). Of course, you also need to configure caching.